# How to check if specific value is present in a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm using Rails and I have a hash object. I want to search the hash for a specific value. I don't know the keys associated with that value.

How do I check if a specific value is present in a hash? Also, how do I find the key associated with that specific value?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Hash includes [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html), so you can use the many methods on that module to traverse the hash. It also has this handy method:

```
hash.has_value?(value_you_seek)
```

To find the key associated with that value:

```
hash.key(value_you_seek)
```

This [API documentation for Ruby (1.9.2)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/) should be helpful.

Comment: This doesn't traverse nested hashes

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to check multiple values are present in a hash is:

```
h = { a: :b, c: :d }
h.values_at(:a, :c).all? #=> true
h.values_at(:a, :x).all? #=> false
```

In case you need to check also on blank values in Rails with ActiveSupport:

```
h.values_at(:a, :c).all?(&:present?)
```

or

```
h.values_at(:a, :c).none?(&:blank?)
```

The same in Ruby without ActiveSupport could be done by passing a block:

```
h.values_at(:a, :c).all? { |i| i && !i.empty? }
```

Comment: `h.values_at(:a, :c).all?(&:present?)` does not work

Comment: @DavidMauricio could you provide an example that doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 4):

[Hash.has_value?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-has_value-3F) and [Hash.key](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-key).

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you have the following `Array` of hashes

`available_sports = [{name:'baseball', label:'MLB Baseball'},{name:'tackle_football', label:'NFL Football'}]`

Doing something like this will do the trick

`available_sports.any? {|h| h['name'] == 'basketball'}`

`=> false`

---

`available_sports.any? {|h| h['name'] == 'tackle_football'}`

`=> true`

Answer (score 2):

While `Hash#has_key?` works but, as Matz wrote [here](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/43765), it has been deprecated in favour of `Hash#key?`.

`Hash`'s `key?` method tells you whether a given key is present or not.

```
hash.key?(:some_key)
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `Hash` has the [select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) method which will return a new hash of entries for which the block is true;

```
h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => 300 }
h.select {|k,v| v == 200}  #=> {"b" => 200}
```

This way you'll search by value, and get your key!

Comment: Why do this when Hash has built in methods?

Answer (score 1):

If you do `hash.values`, you now have an array.

On arrays you can utilize the Enumerable search method [include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F)

```
hash.values.include?(value_you_seek)
```

Comment: it requires O(1) operations to find a key in the hash, but O(n) operations to find a key in array.

Answer (score -2):

An even shorter version that you could use would be `hash.values`